# SQL - Select rows of a table that have similar characteristics of other rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to return only the rows of a table that have similar answers in SOME of the columns, but not all of the columns. Example:

I have the following table and I'm trying to return just the rows where Frank and Joe are eating the same 'Meal', and the same 'Time', and the same 'Location'.

[image]

Returns this:

[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: On hold? I find the question quite clear...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE Attendee IN ('Frank', 'Joe')
AND Meal = 'Lunch'
AND Time = '12:00'
AND Location = 'Cafeteria'
```

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/

Edit: to select all rows where they share a common meal, time, and location (not just one), try this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t1 WHERE Attendee = 'Frank'
JOIN (SELECT * FROM my_table t2 WHERE Attendee = 'Joe')
    ON (t1.Meal = t2.Meal
        AND t1.Time = t2.Time
        AND t1.Location = t2.Location
    )
```

Comment: The problem here is that I'm looking for any meal, at any time, at any location... just as long as Frank and Joe are both there.

Comment: I added a more general version that uses an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intersect` to do this.

```
select * from tablename 
where (meal, time, location) in 
(
select meal, time, location from tablename where attendee = 'Frank'
intersect 
select meal, time, location from tablename where attendee = 'Joe'
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to group by similar fields (in the partition by clause) then limit your records to those with more than one record:

```
SELECT  ApptID, Meal, Time, Location, Attendee
FROM    (   SELECT  ApptID, 
                    Meal, 
                    Time, 
                    Location, 
                    Attendee,
                    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Meal, Time, Location) AS CountOfOccurrences
            FROM    T
        ) AS T
WHERE   CountOfOccurrences > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner join to generalize your query and get all the matching of the same column values (in this case meal, time, location) on different attendees. Something like this:

```
select tb1.attendee, tb1.location, tb1.time, tb1.meal
from yourtbable as tb1
inner join yourtbable as tb2
on ( tb1.meal = tb2.meal 
     and tb1.location = tb2.location 
     and tb1.time = tb2.time 
     and tb1.attendee <> tb2.attendee)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - isn't SQL wonderful - so many different ways:

```
select tf.name, tj.name, meal, time, location
from (select * from tablename where attendee = 'Frank') tf
join (select * from tablename where attendee = 'Joe') tj using (meal, time, location)
```

The join's `USING (meal, time, location)` syntax is basically the same as `ON tf.meal = tj.meal AND tf.time = tj.time AND tf.location = tj.location`, but with the difference that the result has only one each of the columns specified in the `USING` clause. These columns are *table-free*, as you can notice in the select-list.